# Filemanager is to get absolute path

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsfilemanager

I'm looking for a way to extract the absolute path of a file when I'm just providing the filename (NSString)

I'm getting the filename using this:

```
NSString* filename = [[name lastPathComponent] stringByDeletingPathExtension];
```

but I do not find a way to get the absolute path of this file.

When I used to work with Qt, I was using the QFileInfo class to get what I want.

Any idea ?

Comment: Have you tried Google OR StackOverflow?

Comment: @Gajendra yes, but nothing come up for the absolute path

Comment: @Geb AFAIK that is not possible in OS X. You can't get absolute path by just providing the fileName. A lot of files may be present on the system with that same name and OS doesn't know which one you want.

It will be great to share the use case where you want to use this. May be I can give some idea on that!

Comment: @bikram990 the use case is : get a file from your mac and drag'ndrop it into my application. The pointer contain the list of files we are trying to drop into the app. I need to extract the data for each files listed in the DnD action